# Animation Nodes Offset Matrix

Tags: animation, node-editor, animation-nodes

While using AN 2.1 and following a few online tutorials that use AN 2.0 I've found out that the 'Offset Matrix' node is missing the options for Start/End. Is there a workaround to imitate these options by adding another node?

[image: Comparison of both version nodes]

A solution will be enough, but if somebody can explain it a bit better that would be amazing.

Comment: Please use the [animation-nodes] tage to ask questions related to Animation Nodes in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Blender Stackexchange! In the old node, the *End* option simply inverted the Falloff. So to have the same effect, you can invert the Falloff before inputting it using the *[Invert Falloff Node](https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/nodes/falloff/invert_falloff.html)*. This is described in the [documentation](https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/nodes/matrix/offset_matrices.html) of the node:

> *Start* option will offset the matrices based on the offset parameters with the falloff as a factor. *End* option will offset the matrices based on the offset parameters with the inverse falloff as a factor, in other words, all matrices will be transformed based on the offset parameters and then matrices will be transformed back to their initial position based on the offset parameter with the falloff as a factor.